# quote marks in sql causing problems

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I have a simple html input textbox in a very simple form. the information form this form is transmitted to a mysql database with an sql string.

Everything works slick, except when someone types " or '. I don't want to limit the users as to what they can type.

Should I do a find and replace to the string before I run the query against the database?

Is there a simple way?

here's some code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['user']) && empty($_REQUEST['form'])) //check this code!!1
{
    exit;
}
if (isset($_REQUEST['Submit']))
{
    //echo "Let's process this form!";
    include "config.php";
    include "mail.php";
    if ($_REQUEST['form'] == "profile")
    {//public profile
        //print_r($_REQUEST);
        //"UPDATE `tims`.`pending_profile` SET `nickname` = 'I Don''t Have One' WHERE `pending_profile`.`id` = 1;";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `tims`.`pending_profile`"
                . "(`id`, `nickname`, `location`, `role`, `yog`, `interests`, `favMoment`, `gainThisYr`, `futurePlans`, `bio`) \n"
                . "VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['id'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['nickname'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['town'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['role'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['yog'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['interests'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['fav_moment'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['gain'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['future'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['bio'] . "')\n"
                . "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nickname ='" . $_REQUEST['nickname'] . "', location='" . $_REQUEST['town'] . "', role= '" . $_REQUEST['role'] . "', yog='" . $_REQUEST['yog'] . "', interests='" . $_REQUEST['interests'] . "', favMoment='" . $_REQUEST['fav_moment'] . "', gainThisYr='" . $_REQUEST['gain'] . "', futurePlans='" .       $_REQUEST['future'] . "', bio='" . $_REQUEST['bio'] . "'\n";  
        $qry = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

//@todo overlay this
//http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html
        //send mail to moderators
        include "vars.php";
        $to = $captMail;
        $prof = implode("\n", $_REQUEST);
        $subject = "Moderation Needed";
        $body = $_SESSION['fullname'] . " Has just changed their public profile.\n" .
                "Please login here to moderate their changes:\n" .
                //"http://team2648.com/OPIS/login.php?page=manage".
                "http://www." . $sysurl . "/login.php?page=manage\n" .
                "Best,\n" .
                "Blake\n\n\n" .
                "Click here to accept the profile bleow\n\n" .
                "http://www." . $sysurl . "/login.php?page=manage&acceptID=".$_SESSION['id']."\n" .
                $prof;
        mailer($to, $subject, $body);
        $to = $mentorMail;
        mailer($to, $subject, $body);

        echo "<link href=\"../css/styling.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen\" />";
        echo "<div class =\"widget\" style=\"width:350px\">";
        echo "Your changes have been saved, they will not go live until reviewed by a moderator";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<a href=\"../\">Click here to continue</a>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    exit;
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `pending_profile` WHERE id ='" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'";
$qry = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
?>
<!--<h3>Use this page to manage your profile information</h3>-->
<h4>Public Profile</h4>
<strong>NOTE:</strong> Fields filled with [NONE] will not show on the website.
<br />
<form id="profile" name="profile" method="get" action="lib/preview.php">
    <input type="hidden" value="profile" name="form">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>" name="id">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="myname">Hello, My name is:</label><td>
            <td><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="myname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?>"/><td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="nickname">But I like to be called:</label><td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nickname" value="<?php echo $row['nickname']; ?>"/><td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="town">I live in:</label><td>
            <td><input type="text" name="town" value="<?php echo $row['location']; ?>"/><td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="role">My role on the team is:</label><td>
            <td><input type="text" name="role" value="<?php echo $row['role']; ?>"/><td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="yog">I will graduate High School in:</label><td>
            <td><input type="text" name="yog" value="<?php echo $row['yog']; ?>"/><td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="interests">Some of my interests are:</label><td>
            <td><input type="text" name="interests" value="<?php echo $row['interests']; ?>"/><td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="fav_moment">One of my favorite team moments:</label><td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fav_moment" value="<?php echo $row['favMoment']; ?>"/><td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="gain">I would like to gain the following this year:</label><td>
            <td><input type="text" name="gain" value="<?php echo $row['gainThisYr']; ?>"/><td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="future">My future plans include:</label><td>
            <td><input type="text" name="future" value="<?php echo $row['futurePlans']; ?>"/><td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="bio">My Bio:</label><td>
            <td><textarea name="bio" ><?php echo $row['bio']; ?></textarea><td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    * All fields are required.
<?php
include "disclaimer.php";
// @todo add js validation of all fields filled in
?>
    <br><input type="submit" name="Submit" value=" I Agree, Preview "/>

</form>
```

Comment: Read up on SQL Injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection

Comment: So how do I un escape them when I take them out of the database?

Comment: Also, take a look at this if you want to know what can happen if you do not care enough about SQL injection, because Mom says it: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Wow, what's with all the phantom downvotes in this thread?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel -- I was merely pointing out that an explanation for the downvotes might have been appreciate by the recipients.  No need to be condescending.  Have a good one.

Comment: Wow, sounds like someone missed his nap and cookies!

Comment: @Bill I just miss professional answers on this enthusiast site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use the function [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on **all** your user inputs before you put them in the database.

For example:

change `$_REQUEST['nickname']` to `mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['nickname'])`

Alternatively use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: Not "you can", "you absolutely must".

Comment: stupid "user input" again. as though no need to escape quotes in admin input. and stupid "user input" instead of strings. use this function on unquoted number and eat your injection.

Comment: here you can see a fresh example of the consequences of such stupid assumptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814770/quote-marks-in-sql-causing-problems/3814887#3814887 SQL injection at it's best.

Comment: @delnan: No, you needn't use it on any and all of a user's input. If you validate the input before you run a query there is absolutely no risk of an injection. @Col: User input includes input by an administrator. It has nothing to do with your rights on a page.

Comment: @nikic go tell it to all these noobs. And admin input is just a figure. It can be script generated data or anything. Why to mention stupid user input at all, while just every friggin string in the query must be escaped, no matter of it's origin? As for your "no need", **validation rules may change**. Data validation has absolutely nothing to do with database level.

Comment: @nikic: Yeah, it's not necessary if the input is validated properly. But it's obviously safer to escape unnecessarily than not to escape even though you screwed up validation (or didn't validate at all). So as a rule of thumb, one should indeed escape everything.

Comment: @Col: No, you are mistaken. You don't *need* to escape all data passed into the query. If you can be infallibly sure that the string may not be malicious (e.g. because it's `ctype_digit`) then you don't *need* to escape it - but obviously you can. I do know that to err is human and thus it may be inadvisable to rely on your assumption being right. This is why I use an automated quoting system which combines security with convenience. But before I did so I escaped only what required escaping - and I don't see why this is wrong.

Comment: @nikic: Know what is written on the some fellow electrician's grave? "I was sure that power was off".

Answer (score 11):

Your code is filled with [sql injection opportunities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). Or atleast [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). Do not use your code.

Also...

Don't use $_REQUEST. Use the appropriate global $_POST or $_GET. GET requests should not change anything so you should be using $_POST.

Answer (score 5):

Always use parameterized queries when accessing a database.  Constructing dynamic SQL statements as you're doing is an invitation to SQL injection attacks (as well as the errors that you're seeing.)

In PHP, the code to do this looks like

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
```

(shamelessly taken from the PHP manual).

Comment: +1 But I'll add that using parameters is a lot easier in PDO.  I find the mysqli API harder to use.

Answer (score 4):

As other people have mentioned, you need to handle literal quote characters in your strings or else you're susceptible to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

See my presentation [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies) for more examples and solutions.

Using query parameters is an effective defense and it's actually easier to write and makes your code look nicer.  I recommend using PDO, because it allows you to use named parameters.

Also consider using PHP's [heredoc syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to make it simpler to write SQL code, without worrying about all the double-quotes and concatenating strings.

```
$sql = <<<END_SQL
INSERT INTO `tims`.`pending_profile`
(`id`, `nickname`, `location`, `role`, `yog`, `interests`, `favMoment`,
 `gainThisYr`, `futurePlans`, `bio`)
VALUES (:id, :nickname, :town, :role:, :yog, :interests, :fav_moment, 
 :gain, :future, :bio)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  nickname    = :nickname,
  location    = :town,
  role        = :role,
  yog         = :yog,
  interests   = :interests,
  favMoment   = :fav_moment,
  gainThisYr  = :gain,
  futurePlans = :future,
  bio         = :bio
END_SQL;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$success = $stmt->execute(array(
    ':id'         => (int) $_SESSION['id'],
    ':nickname'   => $_POST['nickname'],
    ':town'       => $_POST['town'],
    ':role'       => $_POST['role'],
    ':yog'        => $_POST['yog'],
    ':interests'  => $_POST['interests'],
    ':fav_moment' => $_POST['fav_moment'],
    ':gain'       => $_POST['gain'],
    ':future'     => $_POST['future'],
    ':bio'        => $_POST['bio'],
));
```

*note:* I changed $_REQUEST to $_POST because you should never use a GET request that modifies your data.  Search engines follow links, so you could find Google crawling your site and inadvertently modifying your database.  Always use POST requests when the action is going to store or modify something.

For simple cases you don't even have to use parameters, if you can coerce your variable into something that is safe to use, like a plain integer:

```
$id = (int) $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `pending_profile` WHERE id = {$id}";
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

Aside from the SQL injection risk your code is also full of a different type of security risk, called [Cross-Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), or XSS.  This happens when you echo user-supplied content to the HTML output, without escaping characters that are special in HTML, like `<` or `&`.  Attackers can cause mischief by entering their name including javascript code.

The fix for XSS is basically to use `htmlentities()` on anything you echo, if it might have come from user input or any other non-trusted source (like reading from a database or a file or a web service).

```
<td><input type="text" name="nickname" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['nickname']); ?>"/><td>
```

You really need to study these security flaws if you write code for the web.  They are a source of a lot of trouble on the internet.  See [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/) or the [SANS Top 25 Most Dangerous Software Errors](http://www.sans.org/top25-software-errors/).

Comment: +1 but I find it incredible boring to type the same set of fields **six** times. Not to mention a case what one field being added to the table... There ought to be some helper function to make programmer's job a bit more intellectual.

Comment: @Col Shrapnel:  If you use positional parameters with `?` placeholders, you'd only have to type the names three times instead of six.  But in this example of INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, you'd have to pass each value twice (one can use `array_merge()` to help with that).

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php);

Answer (score 3):

You're going to get beat up for not sanitizing the variables from your form before inserting them into your DB.

The PHP Manual has examples for filtering/sanitizing here....

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Another popular approach since you're using php and mysql is something like this...

```
$var = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['var']);
```

More info here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `(int)` if `$_POST` variable is has to be number.

Answer (score 1):

Everyplace where you use a value that can have quotes use the `addslashes($mystringwithquotes)` method to add slashes before the quotes.

Make sure to not put this around the complete SQL string as you still want to keep the ones you need.

For example in your code:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `tims`.`pending_profile`" 
                . "(`id`, `nickname`, `location`, `role`, `yog`, `interests`, `favMoment`, `gainThisYr`, `futurePlans`, `bio`) \n" 
                . "VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['id'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['nickname'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['town'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['role'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['yog'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['interests'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['fav_moment'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['gain'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['future'] . "', '" . $_REQUEST['bio'] . "')\n" 
                . "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nickname ='" . $_REQUEST['nickname'] . "', location='" . $_REQUEST['town'] . "', role= '" . $_REQUEST['role'] . "', yog='" . $_REQUEST['yog'] . "', interests='" . $_REQUEST['interests'] . "', favMoment='" . $_REQUEST['fav_moment'] . "', gainThisYr='" . $_REQUEST['gain'] . "', futurePlans='" .       $_REQUEST['future'] . "', bio='" . $_REQUEST['bio'] . "'\n";   
        $qry = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

You want to put it around the values `addslashes($_SESSION['id'])`, `addslashes($_SESSION['nickname'])`, etc. but NOT around

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO `tims`.`pending_profile`"
```

Comment: Please don't recommend using addslashes for SQL injection defense.  It's not the right solution because it doesn't account for multibyte character sets.  Use the escaping function provided by the database API: e.g. mysql_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 0):

Using traditional "plain" (not parametrized) queries you have to follow 3 rules

- all strings (quoted portions of data) must be escaped
- all numbers must be cast to its type explicitly
- all identifiers or operators should be chosen from previously defined variants.

you can also use some helper function to assemble your query automatically.

```
function dbSet($fields,&$source) {
  $set='';
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset($source[$field])) {
      $set.="`$field`='".mysql_real_escape_string($source[$field])."', ";
    }
  }
  return substr($set, 0, -2); 
}
```

but your code is tooo dirty to make a working example out of it.
Here is dummy one

```
$fields = explode(" ","name surname lastname address zip fax phone");
$query  = "INSERT INTO $table SET ".dbSet($fields, $_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

For future folks this worked for me

`string addslashes ( string $str )`

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>   addslashes — Quote string with slashes
>
> Returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be escaped. These characters are single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash () and NUL (the NULL byte).
>   [Read more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O'Reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O\'Reilly?
echo addslashes($str);
?>
```